# creating dynamic controls with mvc4 and apply validation to only some fields

Tags: asp.net-mvc, validation, c#-4.0, data-annotations

I am using MVC4 to build an application that is a question generator allowing a user to ask a bunch of questions and to set with a true/false if they are required or not.

I am now onto the part of generating the questions ready for a user to answer the questions.

I want to enable both serverside and clientside validation.

What is the best approach for applying required fields to the questions that have been set to required?

If I have a simple model and view model like

```
 public class TestModel
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Question { get; set; }
    public bool Required { get; set; }
}

public class TestViewModel
{
    public string TestName { get; set; }
    public List<TestModel> Tests { get; set; }
}
```

I can't just add a [Required] Attribute to the Question property

Is it possible to apply validate only to qeustions where the Required property is set to true?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could easily achieve that with the [MVC Foolproof](http://foolproof.codeplex.com/) NuGet:

Simply install it:

```
install-package foolproof
```

And now you could have the following models:

```
public class TestModel
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Question { get; set; }

    [RequiredIf("Required", true)]
    public string Answer { get; set; }
    public bool Required { get; set; }
}

public class TestViewModel
{
    public string TestName { get; set; }
    public List<TestModel> Tests { get; set; }
}
```

a controller:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var model = new TestViewModel
        {
            TestName = "The test",
            Tests = new[]
            {
                new TestModel { Id = Guid.NewGuid(), Question = "q1", Required = true },
                new TestModel { Id = Guid.NewGuid(), Question = "q2", Required = true },
                new TestModel { Id = Guid.NewGuid(), Question = "q3", Required = false },
                new TestModel { Id = Guid.NewGuid(), Question = "q4", Required = true },
            }.ToList()
        };
        return View(model);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(TestViewModel model)
    {
        return View(model);
    }
}
```

a corresponding `~/Views/Index.cshtml` view:

```
@model TestViewModel

<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/mvcfoolproof.unobtrusive.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>

<h2>@Html.DisplayFor(x => x.TestName)</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.TestName)
    @Html.EditorFor(x => x.Tests)
    <button type="submit">OK</button>
}
```

and finally the custom editor template for the TestModel (`~/Views/Home/EditorTemplates/TestModel.cshtml`):

```
@model TestModel

<div>
    @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.Id)
    @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.Required)
    @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.Question)
    @Html.LabelFor(x => x.Answer, Model.Question)
    @Html.EditorFor(x => x.Answer)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.Answer)
</div>
```

Comment: Wow! thank you Darin for such a detailed answer. I Appreciate the time you have taken.